# android - How to show Chinese character getting from inuptstream

Tags: android

When I outputted English string in php file, the app could show the message by toast getting from inputstream. However, When I outputted Chinese String in php file, I did the following code to convert into UTF-8 and I couldn't get the Chinese string.

java:

```
InputStream IS = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(IS,"ISO-8859-1"));
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
String getresult = "";
while((getresult = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
       result.append(getresult);
}
bufferedReader.close();
IS.close();
String resultstring = result.toString();
return resultstring.getBytes("UTF-8").toString();
```

When I did the conversion, the message showed non-Chinese string. How can I show Chinese string getting from server.

Comment: So what encoding is used on the server side? I doubt it's "ISO-8859-1", otherwise I don't see how you can send Chinese string from the php. And why do you want utf-8 in Java? Java doesn't use utf-8 natively, it's Utf-16. ... so I think you are sending Utf8 string from server to Android, right?

Comment: How can I find what encoding the server uses by default? If it is "ISO-8859-1", the sever convert the Chinese string into "ISO-8859-1", isn't it? And, what I need to do is converting "ISO-8859-1" back to "UTF-8" to show Chinese string.

Comment: I don't think I'm sending "UTF-8" string from server to Android. As I've tried to return result.toString();, it gave me garbage.

Comment: WHAT? Why do you do anything with Java `String` on Utf-8 bytes without proper conversion (see my answer). You can't mix anything with everything. If you need to debug what you receive from server, read BYTES first, and display those as hexa numbers. After you know you receive the correct bytes, try to process them... If you let the String mangle the input immediately, without even knowing what encoding was used, you can't debug what was received in network layer.

Comment: If you are talking about my answer, that it returns garbage, test it first with that "test" piece of code (feeding it with `{0xE7, 0x9A, 0x84}` bytes), it should display the 的 ... Then try to send 的 from server (in Utf-8), and check what bytes are received.

Comment: BTW, there's no such thing as encoding Chinese string into ISO-8859-1. That doesn't have chinese glyphs, so it's lossy conversion. You can send utf-8 bytes over ISO-8859-1 channel and they will very likely arrive correctly (unless the channel does some very strong ISO-8859-1 enforcing), but on the receiver end you again don't do anything with ISO-8859-1 in such case. You receive the bytes as they are, and consider them Utf-8 straight away. Your code is reading the input stream as ISO-8859-1, ruining any chance to recover Utf-8 from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To receive UTF-8 strings from network:

```
public static final Charset CHARSET_UTF8 = Charset.forName("UTF-8");

public static String receiveUtf8String(final InputStream is) throws Throwable {
    if (null == is) return null;
    final BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(is, CHARSET_UTF8));
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    String getresult = "";
    while ((getresult = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        result.append(getresult);
        //BTW, this will join multiple lines into single one!
    }
    bufferedReader.close();
    is.close();
    return result.toString();
}
```

To test it:

```
    //的 in UTF-8 for test
    final byte[] buf = {(byte) 0xE7, (byte) 0x9A, (byte) 0x84};
    final ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(buf);
    try {
        String test = receiveUtf8String(is);
        System.out.println("Test: " + test);
    } catch (Throwable throwable) {
        System.out.println("ERROR: " + throwable.getMessage());
    }
```

---

About server encoding being ISO-8859-1.
Well, that's bad, because strictly speaking that should damage the UTF-8 string when being send to ISO-8859-1 output.

So the correct way is to fix server side encoding to Utf8, if you want to send Utf8 strings.

But if the server doesn't do any strong encoding validation, and you send Utf8 bytes on the output (directly, without any conversion), it may get trough as Utf8 bytes (as Utf8 is generally almost backward compatible with 8b extended ASCII, and ISO-8859-1 is 8 bit encoding too).

So verify first what bytes do you receive from server, if it is undamaged Utf8 (see my example for that single glyph encoding). If not, reconfigure server.

You don't want ISO-8859-1 anywhere, why? It's useless. Everything the ISO-8859-1 can handle can handle the Utf-8 just as well, but Utf-8 can handle also international glyphs (although if you are going to send lot of Chinese glyphs, you may consider using Utf-16 on the server side, to get 50% less traffic).

Comment: Also the PHP sources can be Utf-8, PHP can handle that. I sort of wonder where you even get "ISO-8859-1", what OS is still using that? Are you running the server on some MS-DOS, or MS-Windows, or some other piece of history?

Comment: I simply change the encoding of php into utf-8 for saving time.

Answer (score 1):

You should change all your encoding to utf-8, and your outputted Chinese String in php file should use utf-8 coding.

Comment: Is it necessary to change php to utf-8 encoding? I saw some post that the developer got ISO-8859-1 string and convert it into utf-8.

Comment: Just try it, because the same encoding can reduce a lot of trouble.

Comment: I also had the same problem before, and the reason is the server encode is not same with client. when I use the same encoding, the problem is gone.

Comment: Different coding in parsing may produce a garbled

Comment: I know your confusion, "ISO-8859-1" does not support Chinese

Comment: ISO-8859-1 is for English and I convert it into utf-8 by resultstring.getBytes("UTF-8").toString()